# Vim command with count and motion possible?

Tags: vim

My core question is how to create a custom mapping that allows for count and motion. But I would like the count to override the motion. To clarify I want the following to work:

`[count][cmd]` - Do something useful on [count] lines, and not wait for [motion].

`[cmd][motion]` - Do something useful in the range of [motion] of lines.

My exact scenario is trying to add comments to lines, but I would use this information for other mappings in my vimrc. Here is what I have so far.

```
"comment motion of lines
nmap <silent> ,c  :set opfunc=Comment<CR>g@
"comment count lines
nmap <silent> ,cc :s/^/\/\//<CR>:noh<CR>

function! Comment(...)
        silent exe "'[,']s/^/\\/\\//"
        silent exe "noh"
endfunction
```

`,c[motion]` Comments a line by motion. `[count],cc` Comments a line by count.

I would like `,c[motion]` and `[count],c` to work.

Is this possible?

EDIT: clarified my quesiton. Changed "range" to "count"

Comment: advantage of creating solutions encapsulated within functions is that you can maintain a list of jumps and changes through the command keepjumps' for more details see: h keepjumps

I have some functions that use this feature: https://bitbucket.org/sergio/vimfiles/src/7e15525eed4a/vimrc

Comment: I am not having a problem keeping jump states, thanks though.

Comment: By range, do you mean a [count](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#count), like typing `5dd` to delete five lines in normal mode? Or do you really mean a [range](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#cmdline-ranges), like typing `:.,.+4d` to delete five lines in ex mode?

Comment: Good question. I simply mean like 5dd, a real range is not necessary here. I have been fiddling with <count>, but am still falling short. Count is probably a better term for what I am trying to accomplish rather than range.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function s:ExecuteCountOrMotion()
    setlocal operatorfunc=Comment
    if v:count is 0
        return 'g@'
    else
        return 'g@g@'
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> ,c <SID>ExecuteCountOrMotion()
```

By the way, you don't need execute:

1. Instead of `silent exe "{range}s/.../.../"` you should write `{range}s/.../.../e`.
2. You can use `s#^#//#e` to avoid escaping.
3. `silent nohl` works just as well as `silent execute "nohl"`, but causes vim not to do parsing of additional line.

Comment: Thank you very much! Especially for the three helpful hints.

Comment: Thanks Zyx, I didn't think I would find what I was googling for so quickly, but this answer came up first and the pointer to v:count was just what I needed.